# por que no corren los Script de PHP, pero si corre "phpinfo();"?

Tags: php, linux, web, ubuntu, apache2

estoy trabajando con una arquitectura LAMP, con servidor  apache2, php7.0 y MYSql, en ubuntu 16.04, e logrado configurar la ruta para mi desarrollo, en este caso, que pase de `/var/www/` a `/var/www/html/midesarrollo`, para probarlo cree un archivo phpinfo de la siguiente forma `<?php  phpinfo(); ?>` llamado **Hola.php**, dejando la siguiente salida:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo, cuando intento acceder a mi **index.html**, no me presenta nada; el codigo de index.html es una llamada a tres archivos .php, `require_once("mod/Header.php");
require_once("mod/body.php");
require_once("mod/footer.php");`

cuando inspecciono el elemento con el navegador tengo la siguiente salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde  se observa que comenta el script de **php**, lo cual, no debería de pasar debido a que **php** esta en el servidor y  **php**  funciona, como se ve en la primera imagen, pero falla como se ve en la segunda imagen, en este momento no se que pueda suceder, lo que e leído me indica que posiblemente no este el modulo `libapache2-mod-php7.0`, pero este modulo lo he instalado con php, por otro lado cambie la ext del archivo .html a .php, aun que esto no debería ser relevante. pero los resultados fueron los mismos.

Agradezco me puedan ayudar.

Comment: El index debería ser .php también no index.html

Comment: El archivo debe crearlo con extensión  `.php` de lo contrario el código `PHP` no se compila.

Comment: Además agrega el charset utf-8 a tu estructura html

Comment: Muchas gracias, me parece  extraño, creí que el servidor reconocería  el script  en un .html, lo cual parece que no, agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los archivos que mostrarán lógica de programación por ejemplo de lenguajes como **PHP**, necesitan tener la misma extensión.

En caso contrario si le pones **.html**, leerá tus declaraciones de require como una cadena de texto normal ignorando las llamadas que intentas hacer:

Explicado lo anterior, renombra tu archivo de index.html a index.php, la estructura que te debería quedar entonces por dentro es la siguiente:

```
<?php

require_once("mod/Header.php");
require_once("mod/body.php");
require_once("mod/footer.php");
```

También será conveniente por la interpretación de los juegos de caracteres que declares el meta charset correspondiente, en el archivo que se llama header.php por que asumo que ese archivo tiene la parte superior de la estructura HTML como en el **ejemplo** siguiente

> El meta charset utf-8 ayuda a evitar que palabras con caracteres
>   especiales como ñ y acentos se muestren de manera extraña

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"><!--esta etiqueta incluyela-->
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: hola @Shadow Paz, primero que todo gracias, e corregido la extencion, del archivo, y a funcionado correctamente, me gustaria poder ejecutar el script php de un .html, existe alguna forma para eso?, de antemano Gracias.

Comment: explicame mas a detalle que deseas hacer, no me quedó claro tu comentario

Comment: si claro, es que, recuerdo que con alguna configuración en apache, es posible que este identifique los script **php** en un .html, pero no recuerdo como se hace esto, o si esto es posible.

Comment: hasta donde tengo conocimiento no, y de todos modos ese no es el procedimiento regular de trabajo que te vas a encontrar en escenarios laborales reales; te recomiendo trabajar del modo que te comento

Comment: Gracias, por tu ayuda. lo tendré presente

Comment: para ejecutar html como php tenes que configurar el apache, puede ser en el config global o por carpetas con .htaccess . 
Como no es enteramente el scope de la pregunta dejo el link para el que le interese http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#sethandler